# How to install docker daemon when resizing data center cluster size in Mesosphere?

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere

We're thinking about using mesos and mesosphere to host our docker containers. Reading the [docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/tutorials/launch-docker-container-on-mesosphere/) it says that a prerequisite is that:

> Docker version 1.0.0 or later needs to be installed on each slave
>   node.

We don't want to manually SSH into each new machine and install the correct version of the Docker daemon. Instead we're thinking about using something like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) to install Docker (and perhaps other services that may be required on each slave).

1. Is this a good way to solve it or does Mesosphere/DCOS or any of Mesos ecosystem components have other ways of dealing with this?
2. I've seen the quick [intro](https://youtu.be/UgJMlHdZEx4?t=330) where someone from Mesosphere just use `dcos resize` to change the cluster size on the Google Cloud Platform. Is there a way to hook in to this process and install additional services on the (google) container when it has booted? Or is this something we should avoid and instead just use a "pre-baked image"?

Comment: To clarify (and yes, our docs is updated as we speak): Mesosphere is the company, DCOS (Datacenter Operating System) is our product. With this out of the way: what's your environment (on-premise/cloud) and OS (CentOS, Ubuntu, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this was actually not entirely clear to me. I also wasn't aware that this necessarily was cloud specific (except from GCE) so that's why the question might be a bit broad. We've actually not decided on the environment 100%, but probably GCE, AWS or Linode (or a combination of these). We're OK with changing OS as well if it gives us any simplifications or other benefits but today we're using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your own datacenter using your favorite configuration tool such as ansible, salt, ... is probably a good choice.
On the cloud it might be easier to use virtual machine images providing docker, so for example [dcos on aws](https://mesosphere.com/product/) uses coreOS which comes with docker out of the box. Shouldn't be too difficult with Ubuntu either...

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a "hook" or something for installing things when a new container boots up (question 2 above)?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet (with new container you mean new node, correct?). But depending on your image (and autherization settings) the new node could just join the existing mesos cluster...

Comment: Yes I meant "node" just as you implied, was a bit too fast on the keyboard.